# wget not working for shared files in Google drive

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a file from Google drive using `wget` command but it is not working.

```
wget https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8ZGlkqDw7hFUzViMXE4akp4NGM
```

It is giving me the following error.

```
Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... 172.217.7.238
Connecting to drive.google.com (drive.google.com)|172.217.7.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2017-06-30 16:49:26 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

The file is public on web and anyone can download it directly with the provided link. So, why it is not working with wget?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Works for me with quotes:

```
wget "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8ZGlkqDw7hFUzViMXE4akp4NGM"
```

P.S. Looks like the ampersand is the problem. An alternative might be to escape them separately, but quoting seems simpler and safer.