# Download Google Drive File to Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: unix, curl, wget

I am trying to download the files in the following link via wget:

[Google landmark competitions files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_cQXGzqzbF5eL_UmITdZqlEAM7_rgI4c)

I have tried the solutions proposed in the following answers but have been unable to get it to work.

1. [wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive)
2. [Downloading zip folder/file from google drive from shared with me folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597673/downloading-zip-folder-file-from-google-drive-from-shared-with-me-folder)
3. [wget/curl large file from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive/49444877#49444877)
4. [Using Wget on a google drive file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277961/using-wget-on-a-google-drive-file)
5. [Download file from Google Drive via HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510380/download-file-from-google-drive-via-http-get-request)
6. [wget not working for shared files in Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854663/wget-not-working-for-shared-files-in-google-drive)

It continues to download a file that ranges in size from 0K to 3.1K depending on the answer but none of them the .zip files.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you inspected the downloaded files? They may contain the error. Rename them to txt and inspected them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use this to download the files from google drive with `wget`

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

So the two files which you are looking for can be download as follows:

```
>> wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1J5QX6PflSnmXr428i7rWi0dAz80SOzqN' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=1J5QX6PflSnmXr428i7rWi0dAz80SOzqN" -O test.zip && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

```
>> wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1rO1xQzMUNxNobKNDdofgW5VihQkeW3j2' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=1rO1xQzMUNxNobKNDdofgW5VihQkeW3j2" -O train.zip && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You are amazing! I try not to write thank you comments here but this was life saver!